# Changing DateTime format in Java

Tags: java, android, date

I'm using this code to get relative date time in android

```
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long difference = now - this.mReferenceTime;
    if ((0 <= difference) && (DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS >= difference)) {
        return getResources().getString(R.string.just_now);
    } else {
        return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                this.mReferenceTime,
                now,
                DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
                DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE).toString();

    }
```

The output is coming as "28 Mar". How do I make this to "Mar 28"?

This will return strings like "Just now" or "2 minutes ago" or "6 days ago" or something like "28 Mar".
I just wanna change the "28 Mar" part to "Mar 28".

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082518/android-getrelativetime-example

Comment: so whats the answer?

Comment: you can split and swap the output string

Comment: so split and swap? i thought there will be some DateUtils.FORMAT_....

Comment: Can you show what's mReferenceTime and now values? Because i'm testing your code, and it gives me __Jun 14__ with my params

Comment: Why do you set the flag `DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH` if you want a relative time in minutes? This flag seems to be totally inappropriate because it is only for date representations, not for relative times expressing durations. Please clarify.

Comment: According to [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html): `Can use FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE flag to use abbreviated relative times, like "42 mins ago".`

Comment: @NikMyers so could it be a phone settings thing then?

Comment: added full code + explanation

Comment: I still don't understand. How is "28 Mar" (or "Mar 28") a relative time? Relative to what? It rather looks like a date without year, and that format has no reference to now, but the notation of a relative time like "2 mins ago" is just another term for a duration relative to now. You are not supposed to call `getRelativeTimespanString(...)` with a dateformat-flag like `FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH`. An example for the horrible and unsafe design of helper class `DateUtils`.

Comment: It has some limit on how many __days ago__ could be, if difference is larger, that it just showing MONTH DAY, you didn't add your values for __now__ and __ReferenceTime__, i need them to test, just paste long values please

Answer (score 0):

For this output you can use `SimpleDateFormat` like this;

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
String currentDateTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Good luck.

Comment: I think there is one "M" to much

Comment: No, if you use two "M", this output becomes "03 28". It is for the output "Mar 28".

Comment: ya but how to incorporate this in DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString. i also have to get strings like "2 minutes ago" only need format change if its a date like "28 Mar"

Comment: It is about where did you get this date from. You should have a `Date` object in the function `sdf.format()`. Then you can create a `Date` object which is "2 minutes ago".

Answer (score 0):

change your format like this

```
SimpleDateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy.dd.MM HH:mm:ss");
```

you can change your format more ways - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html